# Response to invalid token in Socket.IO

Tags: node.js, socket.io

The following code is working fine, and the client is able to connect only if there is a valid token.
But how can i handle the case of invalid token, i.e. catch error thrown by middleware through next?

Also, is there some way to respond to client?

```
io.use((socket, next) => {
  const token = socket.handshake.headers['authorization'].split(' ');
  if (token === undefined || token === null || token[0] !== 'Bearer')
    return next(new Error('Invalid Token'));
  jwt.verify(token[1], jwtSecretKey, (err, decoded) => {
    if (err) return next(new Error('Invalid Token'));
    console.log(decoded);
    next();
  });
});

io.use() // Handle here, if error thrown by previous middleware

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log(socket.id + ' Connected');
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [socket.io doc](https://socket.io/docs/server-api/), "errors passed to socket.io middleware callbacks are sent as special error packets to clients".

This means that if you call `next(err)`, then it sends that `err` object to the client that looks like it will generate the [`error` message](https://socket.io/docs/client-api/#Event-%E2%80%98error%E2%80%99) back to the client.  There does not appear to be the same type of error handler that Express has.  So, if you want to handle errors in a common place, then instead of calling `next(err)`, you can just create your own error handling function and call it instead `handleErrors(socket, err)`.  Then, you will have all the errors passed to one place and you can decide what to send back to the client.

It seems to me that socket.io messages aren't really analogous to http requests as there's no required response and no standard set of errors.  In fact, most socket.io messages that generate an error would require error handling specific to that type of message, not something a generic handler can necessarily be good at.  For that reason, I'd probably  prefer to just handle the error in the middleware where it first occurs (which may or may not need to send something to the client) and only call some common error handling function if you want some common type of response that you can implement one place.